# Visual Studio 2022 Ignores tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, visual-studio

I've got a project set up with typescript in it. Visual Studio was working correctly with it yesterday but I guess closing it and reopening it has screwed things up. Webpack can build it with no errors but Intellisence is giving me these errors in my files:

[image]

Here is my file structure:

[image: File Structure]

I've set up the tsconfig.json to:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"outDir": "./dist/",
"noImplicitAny": true,
"module": "es6",
"target": "es5",
"jsx": "react",
"allowJs": true,
"moduleResolution": "node",
"paths": {
  "@/*": [ "./src/*" ]
}
},
"include": [ "./declaration.d.ts", "./src/profile-types.d.ts" ],
"exclude": [
   "node_modules"
]
}
```

React-hook-forms is in my package.json and is installed correctly. I just want to get it back to where intellisence was working with everything. It looks like it's ignoring the tsconfig because that's where the types are included and the moduleResolution is set to node. I've tried clearing the temp files and restarting VS but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it was working before, but adding "src/**/*" into the include section of the tsconfig.json fixed the problem for me. Hope this helps whoever else ran into this problem on visual studio.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "./declaration.d.ts",
    "./src/profile-types.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```